# Speed up fig.show interval in knitr

Tags: html, r, animation, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating an html document from an rmarkdown file using knitr and inserting an animation code chunk as follows:

````
```{r,fig.show='animate'}
for(i in 1:10) plot(rnorm(10))
```
````

The animation is created just fine, however, I haven't found a way to speed up the animation.  For instance, the animation package has the `interval` argument for `saveGIF()` which allows one to speed up or slow down a gif.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chunk option `interval` lets you set frame duration, while the `aniopts` option lets you pass in a string containing options that are passed directly on to the LaTeX package **animate**. (Both are documented in the "Animation" section of [the **knitr** package's options documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/))

So, for instance, to speed the animation up 5-fold and provide it with controls but no looping, do this:

````
```{r, fig.show='animate', interval=0.2, aniopts="controls"}
for(i in 1:10) plot(rnorm(10))
```
````